# Serve Jekyll blog on Nginx

Tags: nginx, jekyll, static-files

I am trying to serve a jekyll blog on nginx.
The files in the build directory should be reachable via the following routes:

```
  - index.html -> /
  - 1.0/
    - index.html -> /1.0/
    - foo/
        a.html   -> /1.0/foo/a/
        b.html   -> /1.0/foo/b/
        c.html   -> /1.0/foo/c/
    - bar/
        1.html   -> /1.0/bar/1/
        2.html   -> /1.0/bar/2/
```

I tried to use the try_files directive in nginx but it always calls the fallback although the files are available. Here is the config:

```
location ~* ^(.+)/$ {
  try_files $uri /$1/index.html /$1.html =404;
}
```

If I remove the 404 fallback it only works for the last value.

So my question is: What's the best way to configure nginx for serving static files like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I remove the 404 fallback it only works for the last value.

This is because the last parameter of [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) directive should be an HTTP error code or an URI to try if the file not found. In your case nginx assumes it is an URI.

Try this:

```
location ~ ^(?<path>/.*/)(?<file>[^/]+)/$ {
    try_files $uri $path$file.html $uri/ =404;
}
```

If you want to serve `http://example.com/1.0/foo/a` requests similar to `http://example.com/1.0/foo/a/`, change regex to `^(?<path>/.*/)(?<file>[^/]+)/?$`.

Comment: thanks for your reply but it only works when I remove the last 2 parts

`try_files $uri $path$file.html;`

Comment: That's very strange, I tested this config and it works as expected. Lets clarify some things. Assuming you have a `/1.0/foo/a.html` file under your server root. Request to `http://example.com/1.0/foo/a/` didn't return this file with my config?

Comment: oh my mistake, I was configuring the wrong nginx. I am running a nginx application via dokku and I was changing the dokku nginx instead of the application nginx all the time. Thats the reason. Thank you for figuring it out.